# Include error in writing html file from php

Tags: php, post, get, include

I seem to have some problem with my code here. It creates a file from the php file, but I get an error on the include path.

```
include('../include/config.php');

$name = ($_GET['createname']) ? $_GET['createname'] : $_POST['createname'];

function buildhtml($strphpfile, $strhtmlfile) {
ob_start();
include($strphpfile);
$data = ob_get_contents();
$fp = fopen ($strhtmlfile, "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
ob_end_clean();
}

buildhtml('portfolio.php?name='.$name, "../gallery/".$name.".html");
```

The problem seems to be here:

```
'portfolio.php?name='.$name
```

Any way I can replace this, and still send the variable over?

---

Here's the error I get when I put ?name after the php extension:

```
Warning: include(portfolio.php?name=hyundai) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Projects\Metro Web\Coding\admin\create.php on line 15

Warning: include(portfolio.php?name=hyundai) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Projects\Metro Web\Coding\admin\create.php on line 15

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'portfolio.php?name=hyundai' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Projects\Metro Web\Coding\admin\create.php on line 15
```

Comment: So, where exactly do you think the error comes from? Is it caused by  the `include` or by `'portfolio.php?name='.$name`?

Comment: It seems to work without any error if I dont use `?name='.$name`, so I don't think it's a path problem.

Comment: Are you sure `portfolio.php` is in the same folder `admin/`, next to `create.php`? Could you also provide the signature of the `buildhtml()` function?

Comment: Positive. It works when I don't send a variable with the link. Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: I think so. It makes no sense to me to append `GET` parameters if you're passing the filename as an argument of a function. Are you sure `$name` shouldn't be the second argument of the function `buildhtml`?

Comment: It would be much easier if you provide the source of `buildhtml()`. If it's too long, please consider using [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com). Otherwise it's just *guessing*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I saw your code in the comment to a previous answer I'd like to point few things out

```
function buildhtml($strhtmlfile) {
    ob_start(); // redundant
    $fp = fopen ($strhtmlfile, "w"); // redundant
    file_put_contents($strhtmlfile,
                      file_get_contents("http://host/portfolio.php?name={$name}")); 
//                                       where does $name come from?? ---^
    close($fp); // also redundant
    ob_end_clean(); // also redundant
}
buildhtml('../gallery/'.$name.'.html');
```

In PHP as in many other languages you can do things in different ways. What you've done is you took three different ways and followed only one (which is absolutely enough). So when you use functions `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()` you don't need the buffer, that is the `ob_` family of functions, because you never read anything in the buffer which you should then get with `ob_get_contents()`. Nor you need the file handles created and used by `fopen()`, `fclose()`, because you've never written to or read from the file handle i.e. with `fwrite()` or `fread()`.

If I'm guessing correctly that the purpose of your function is to copy html pages to local files, my proposal would be the following:

```
function buildhtml($dest_path, $name) {
    file_put_contents($dest_path,
                  file_get_contents("http://host/portfolio.php?name={$name}"));
}

buildhtml('../gallery/'.$name.'.html', $name);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code and the info! Really useful! :)

Comment: Took me a while to see the function's definition in your comment and some more to figure out what exactly you were doing, but still Glad I could help! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents($strhtmlfile, file_get_contents("http://host/portfolio.php?name={$name}"))
```

Is it ok?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, I get a blank file. Is there any fix I should consider? Maybe I didn't use the code the right way?

Comment: `function buildhtml($strhtmlfile) {

ob_start();
$fp = fopen ($strhtmlfile, "w");
file_put_contents($strhtmlfile, file_get_contents("http://host/portfolio.php?name={$name}"));
fclose($fp);
ob_end_clean();
}
buildhtml('../gallery/'.$name.'.html');
`

Comment: file_put_contents uses the first parameter as the filename that it should write to. And the second parameter as the data it should write in the previously mentioned file.

Comment: what OP wants to do is to read the data with file_get_contents and capture it into the output buffer. Since file_get_contents returns data rather than echoing it, you need to echo the result of the function call in order for it to be captured in the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The output of:

```
'portfolio.php?name='.$name, "../gallery/".$name.".html";
```

is:

```
portfolio.php?name=[your name]../gallery/[your name].html
```

Are you sure that's what you want ?

Comment: Yes. The `portfolio.php` creates a html file using the `$name` of the selected database entry. It detects how many images with that name exist (name-1.jpg, name-2.jpg, name-3.jpg, etc) and creates a slideshow div in `name.html`.

Comment: @GrozavAlexIoan but the value `[your name]../gallery/[your name].html` is not a valid name for html

Answer (score 0):

include/require statements in PHP allow you to access the code contained in a file which is already stored on the server

What you are trying to achieve is including the output result of executing the code in that file with specific parameters

The suggested example offered by MrSil allows you to request the execution of the code in those files and offer parameters. The reason it shows you a blank page is because file_put_contents 'saves data to a file' and file_get_contents does not echo the result, it returns it. Remove the file_put_contents call, and add an echo at the beginning of the line before file_get_contents and it should work.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://domain.com/file.php?param=1');
```

As a warning this approach forces the execution of 2 separate PHP processes. An include would have executed the code of the second file within the first process.

To make the include approach work you need to include the file as you first did but without specifying parameters. Before including each file you need to setup the  parameters it is expecting such as  $_GET['name'] = $name